# A basic doubt on the quantity $\ln E[e^X]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I heard that the quantity $\ln E[e^X]$ expresses variance of $X$ other than $E[X]$. But, I can't prove it formally ? any help will be appreciated.

i.e. I want to see how $\ln E[e^X] \geq E[X]$ (other than Jensen's inequality) by writting its exxpression (may be Taylor series).

Comment: Why "other than Jensen's inequality"?

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $E[e^{X}]$ is equal to the [Moment Generating Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X$, $M_X(t)$ at $t=1$.

This can be expressed as a power series:

$M_X(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^iE[X^i]}{i!} \implies M_X(1) \geq E[X] $ since all terms in the sum are positive if $t=1$.

Now, lets say that we have a constant random variable X, so that all moments above the first are zero, then $M_X(1)=e^{E[X]}$ and $\ln(M_X(1))>E[X]$. However, truly random variables will have values for at least the second moment, at which point it is not clear if the resulting sum is greater or less than $E[X]$. [Hoffeding's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) provides a case where you can make statements if $X$ is almost surely bounded on $(a,b)$ and $E[X]=0$:

$0\leq E[e^{X}]\leq e^{\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}} \implies \ln(E[e^{X}])\leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{8}$

Now, suppose that $X$ is a uniform RV bounded on $(-1,1)$ then $E[X]=0$ and $\ln(E[e^{X}])\leq \frac{1}{2}> E[X]=0$

So, in the case of zero mean RVs it is true.

If $E[X]=\mu$ and $X\in (\mu-1,\mu+1), a.s.$ then $E[X-\mu]=0 \implies \ln(E[e^{X-\mu}])\leq \frac{1}{2}$, from above. Also, $\ln(E[e^{X-\mu}])=\ln(e^{-\mu}E[e^{X}])=\ln(E[e^{X}])-\mu \leq \frac{1}{2}\implies\ln(E[e^{X}]) \leq \frac{1}{2}+\mu$

So again, we can see that we cannot exclude the possibility that your conjecture is correct. However, Jensen's inequality is quite clear (although you don't want to rely on it for some reason):

Let  $Y=e^{X}$ and $f(s)=\ln(s)$, which is a concave function, then we know that:

$\ln(E[Y])\geq E[\ln(Y)] \implies \ln(E[e^{X}])\geq E[X]$

Combining this with the previous finding for bounded variables, we get:

$ E[X]\leq \ln(E[e^{X}]) \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{8}+E[X]$

Comment: The question is about $\log M_X(1)$ and not about $M_X(1)$. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @saz no you're not...I need to complete this post but got pulled away....must have posted it.

Comment: @saz OK, added in the final part.